# nmap won't recognize a hostname on my local area network

Tags: shell, networking, nmap, lan

Scanning the machine on the LAN with my laptop, I got this:

```
gabriele @ osiris { ~ } [ Tue Oct 07 ] [ 08:49 PM]
 nmap -sP 192.168.1.236

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-07 20:50 CEST
Nmap scan report for ---.homenet.telecomitalia.it (192.168.1.236)
Host is up (0.0044s latency).
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

nmap won't recognize the nostname, putting—in place of "mercury" and I assume is not a problem of nmap because it doesn't even access in this way:

```
root@mercury
```

when I changed the hostname I follow these steps

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

and I wrote a single line with "mercury", then:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

with this configuration:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       mercury localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

and finally:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh start
```

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's probably the result of the reverse DNS lookup. What does `host 192.168.1.236` print?

Comment: 236.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ---.homenet.telecomitalia.it.

Comment: Yep, it looks like the `---.homenet.telecomitalia.it` is coming from your DNS server. If that is your local router provided by your ISP, have a look in the web interface - there could be a way to rename that entry.

Answer (score 0):

change ur /etc/hosts file from

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 127.0.1.1       mercury localhost

to:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 192.168.1.236 mercury

once you do that, "ping mercury" or "nmap mercury" should work, and the inverse, "nmap 192.168.1.236" should then show the hostname associated with that IP in /etc/hosts, in the nmap report output

Comment: Seems doesn't work.

Comment: paste ur output... paste ur hosts file